# Can I set a url to my EC2 instance instead of the IP?

Tags: url, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am working on an AWS EC2 instance, I installed an apache server.
Is it possible to set a url to my server?

I would like to write on my browser:

`http://myServiceWebSite`

instead of

`http://23.26.31.178`

Can I hide the ip of my server by a face name?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set a [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) using a [domain registrar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar) such as [Go Daddy](http://www.godaddy.com/) 
You can use FREE domain names such as [co.nr](http://www.freedomain.co.nr) though I think that 13$ a year for a .com is a descent price.

As ajay wrote, Amazon Does provide a default DNS but it is "ugly" and you will probably not use it.

Comment: Thank you Chen, so I suppose that there is no free trick to do that in AWS?

Comment: By default ec2 gives a public DNS something like ec2-x-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com which can be seen by selecting your instance in console. you can access your instance through this public DNC instead of ip. This is the only free trick available in Amazon ec2. To have your own configured URL you have to have DNS service from subscriber like GoDaddy.com

Comment: Edited my response to add "free domain"

Comment: Thank you ChenHarel and @ajay !

Answer (score 3):

By default, **every time you restart a machine it will probably assign a different IP address**, and the DNS name is ugly because it is based on IP, and it is released on instance shutdown.

If your server is used by the public internet you might have at least 3 choices:

1. Make the IP address static by using [Elastic IP](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#using-instance-addressing-eips) option from EC2 console and register this IP using some DNS Service such as Go Daddy.
2. Leave your IP assigned dynamically and use a dynamic DNS service such as [DynDns](http://dyn.com/dns/).
3. If need to use an Elastic Load Balancer use the [AWS Route 53](https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53) DNS Service, and instead of creating an A Resource Record pointing to a static IP address, you could use an [Alias Resource Record](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingAliasRRSets.html) pointing to your Elastic Load Balancer, I think this would be the **best option** if you have more than 1 server.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a quick and dirty solution, you could use a url shortener and use the url it generates from your default AWS DNS. This is not a long term solution, but just something to use if, for example, you want to deploy a prototype quickly and display it for someone temporarily without handing them an IP address.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I meant using bitly or tinyurl to encode the AWS public DNS of your prototype application. You can give the bitly url to users and they will be redirected to your app on AWS. Again, this is only a temporary solution in case you want to display something quickly, without handing out an IP.